# Hacer una consulta, de dos tablas, relacionadas mediante una tercera

Tags: sql

estaba intentando hacer una consulta en la que intervienen 3 tablas, consultando datos de 2 de ellas (TABLA AUTOR Y LIBRO), que se relacionan mediante los datos contenidos en la 3º(TABLA ESCRIBE)

Este es el código:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTOR (
    CODIGO NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT AUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT NOM_AUTOR_NN NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE LIBRO (
    CODIGO NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT LIBRO_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    TITULO VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT TIT_LIBRO_NN NOT NULL,
    ISBN VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT ISBN_UN UNIQUE,
    EDITORIAL VARCHAR2(30),
    PAGINAS NUMBER(4)
);

CREATE TABLE ESCRIBE(
    CODAUTOR NUMBER(10),
    COD_LIBRO NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT ESCRIBE_PK PRIMARY KEY (CODAUTOR, COD_LIBRO),
    CONSTRAINT CODAUTOR_FK FOREIGN KEY (CODAUTOR) REFERENCES AUTOR (CODIGO) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT CODLIBRO_ESC_FK FOREIGN KEY (COD_LIBRO) REFERENCES LIBRO (CODIGO) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Y esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, TITULO FROM AUTOR, LIBRO, ESCRIBE WHERE autor.codigo=ESCRIBE.codautor, ESCRIBE.COD_LIBRO=LIBRO.COD_LIBRO AND TITULO='EL PRINCIPITO';
```

Se que la sintaxis esta mal de la consulta esta mal, por lo que pido perdón por anticipado.
Espero puedan ayudarme, y confirmame cual es la sintaxis correcta.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en el where no podes poner comas, tienen que ser operadores logicos (or, and)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta está mal armada. La info que necesitás consultar la tenés que traer mediante JOINS:

```
SELECT AUTOR.CODIGO, AUTOR.NOMBRE, LIBRO.CODIGO, LIBRO.TITULO, LIBRO.ISBN, LIBRO.EDITORIAL, LIBRO.PAGINAS
FROM AUTOR
INNER JOIN ESCRIBE ON (ESCRIBE.CODAUTOR = AUTOR.CODIGO)
INNER JOIN ESCRIBE ON (ESCRIBE.COD_LIBRO = LIBRO.CODIGO)
WHERE LIBRO.CODIGO = 'elCodigoDeLibroQueNecesitesBuscar'
```

Si no sabés lo que es un JOIN deberías leer un poco acerca de esto para tener una minima idea de como funcionan. Repasá también los conceptos de consultas de base de datos para saber como estructurar la consulta y revisar la sintaxis de manera correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportacion, y comenzare a informarme sobre el tema.Por al ejecutar

Comment: @ManuelLucas se cortó tu comentario. Te funcionó la Query?

Comment: Si, si funciono, muchas gracias por la aportacion!!

Comment: @ManuelLucas me alegro. No olvides marcar mi respuesta como aceptada y votarla para que futuras personas que tengan la misma duda puedan resolverla.